# Why can't I create this SQLite view using the command line?

Tags: sqlite, shell, sql-view, sqlitestudio

When I run the query below in SQLiteStudio, the view is successfully created.

```
CREATE VIEW BeatsEventsView AS
    SELECT BeatId,
           EventId,
           Hero,
           Beat,
           AdaptationPhase,
           Essence,
           Act,
           Events.[Desc]
      FROM BeatEvents,
           Beats,
           Events
     WHERE (BeatEvents.EventId = Events.Id) AND 
           (BeatEvents.BeatId = Beats.Id);
```

However, I get `Error: near line 1: near "CREATE": syntax error` if I put it into a file and run the command below.

```
sqlite3 $DB_FILE < $BASE_DIR/src/BeatsEventsView.sql.txt
```

How can I create this view in a shell script?

Running the command `file BeatsEventsView.sql.txt` results in this output:

```
BeatsEventsView.sql.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

Comment: Does the file perhaps have a utf-8 byte order mark in the very beginning? Some Windows programs have a nasty habit of adding one.

Comment: @Shawn How can I check this? Note that all of this is happening on a Mac.

Comment: @Shawn See also update 1 in the question.

Comment: Hah, called it! Use a different editor or find the setting in whatever you're using to turn off adding the bom.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks! I fixed the error as described in the answer.

Comment: @Mentiflectax : "How can I check this" ... You already checked this. The output of your `file` command said exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Shawn I fixed the error by adding

`-- -*- mode: sql; coding: utf-8 -*-`

at the beginning of the file so that it looks like shown below.

```
-- -*- mode: sql; coding: utf-8 -*-
CREATE VIEW BeatsEventsView AS
    SELECT BeatId,
           EventId,
...
```

After saving it with Emacs, the `file BeatsEventsView.sql.txt` command now returns

```
BeatsEventsView.sql.txt: ASCII text
```